# AWS Amplify: Error fetching release: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\demes\.amplify\bin\amplify.exe'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have tried to install AWS Amplify and the latest version presents the problem:
Downloading release from https://package.cli.amplify.aws/12.5.0/amplify-pkg-win-x64.tgz                                 Error fetching release: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\demes.amplify\bin\amplify.exe'

When I try and run any amplify commands, I installed it using CMD prompt, NPM, I have node.js installed to the latest version, I have git and all relevant recommended installs.

I have tried a lot of other steps to fix the issues such as clearing the cache, downloading to another directory, using --force and --global. When I checked the directory given in the error, the file amplify.exe doesn't exist in the Bin, I have tried putting it there manually however it just gets deleted, I have checked the permissions and everything looks fine I have all the permissions enabled for this to work.

I am using windows 11, one side note if I try to install a way earlier version such as 4.38.2 it works fine, however there are elements missing from this version which I need, specifically "amplify add api".

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue 15 minutes ago when I tried to install it on my new Windows.

Check your antivirus (prolly Avast for the default one on Windows).
It blocks the binary from being installed, so simply disable the active protection.